# Can't seem to make a corpus from a xlsx with R for text mining

Tags: r, tm, corpus

I am new to R programming and what seems like it should be pretty easy has had me stumped for a good week plus.  My problem is that I cannot seem to get R to construct a proper  corpus and then convert it to a document term matrix (dtm) or term document matrix based off of a xlsx spreadsheet.  The problems I seem to be seem to in 2 areas:

1) The corpus does not read the columns for id, text, and category.
2) It does not yield the proper number of documents in the dtm.

My data structure is a three columned spreadsheet with the following structrure

ID         Terms                    Category
8675309    Jenny Wall Number        Yes

ID is a unique identifier, Terms are meta data terms describing a longer entry, Category is categorical variable that is either yes or no depending if the item is in the group or not.

My code is as follows

```
setwd("c:/users/jared/documents/business/kent project/r directory")
getwd()
#init
install.packages("qdap")
install.packages("xlsx","tm")
install.packages("~/R Scripts/RTextTools_1.4.2.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type =        source")
library(tm)
library(xlsx)
library(RTextTools)

file <- "c:/r directory/R Training.xlsx"


    adf<-anesthesia_df <- read.xlsx(file, 1, as.data.frame=TRUE,header =  TRUE,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

    head(adf)

    #Build and Clean Corpus

    myReader <- readTabular(mapping=list(content="PROJECT_TERMS", id="APPLICATION_ID"))
    adc <- VCorpus(DataframeSource(adf), readerControl=list(reader=myReader))

    inspect(adc)

    head(adc)

    adc <- tm_map(adc, removePunctuation)  
    adc <- tm_map(adc, removeNumbers)  
    adc <- tm_map(adc, tolower) 
    adc <- tm_map(adc, removeWords, stopwords("english"))
    ads <- tm_map(adc, stripWhitespace)
    adc <- tm_map(adc, PlainTextDocument) 
   #docs <-tm_map(docs, stemDocument) 

   adtm<-DocumentTermMatrix(adc)

    inspect(adtm)
    #Create container for RTextTools
    containter<-create_container(adtm, APPLICATION_ID,trainSize = 1:200, testSize = 200:300, virgin=FALSE
```

)

The error that I get is Error in is.factor(x) : object 'APPLICATION_ID' not found.

(I do recognize I have not put in the categorical variable.)

Any ideas?  Thanks.